# how can I use SVML instructions

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd

I am trying to calculate the `exponential` function using SIMD. and I found this function : https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_exp_ps&expand=2136

I have already included `"immintrin.h"` in my code, and also my cpu has a `SSE` flag. But `gcc` is complaining that `error: ‘_mm_exp_pd’ was not declared in this scope`

How could I check whether SVML instructions is enabled ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SVML is a proprietary Intel library that works with the Intel compiler (ICC). If you're not using ICC then you'll need to find an equivalent library, e.g. [sse_mathfun](https://github.com/RJVB/sse_mathfun) or [avx_mathfun](https://github.com/reyoung/avx_mathfun).

**UPDATE**: Visual C++ 2019 supports Intel SVML for x86/x64 architectures.

Comment: A search for svml on my system with the Intel OpenCL SDK runtime installed turned up some svml dlls. My guess is that Intel OpenCL uses SVML i.e. you can get SVML for free indrectly through OpenCL.

Comment: I would also mention [Agner Fog's Library - Vector Class Library (VCL)](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: Note that VS 2019 includes support for SVML

Comment: There's also a [SLEEF](https://sleef.org/) library, planned to be used by LLVM.